# How is a photon converted into matter?

Tags: photons, mass-energy

Photon is a mass less particle but still it can be converted into matter which has mass.

I know the formula $E=mc^2$, but is there some kind of force or particle which converts photons into matter, is it the weak nuclear force?

Comment: Are you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of a pair of photons into an electron/positron pair is simply the time reversal of the anhilation of an electron/positron pair into a pair of photons. The thing that permits the transition is conservation. Specifically, all of the conservation laws are satisfied including energy, momentum, spin, charge, etc. Regardless of which fundamental forces are involved, there is a certain probability of the transition as long as all of the conservation laws are satisfied.

Comment: Note: a pair production event where one photon splits into two electrons is forbidden by conservation of linear momentum. Another photon must be involved in order to balance things (usually this is a virtual photon from an electric field). It's easier to see this in reverse: annihilation of an electron-positron pair in the center-of-mass frame cannot produce only one photon.

Comment: does the week force has to do something with this?

Comment: Compliance with conservation laws is required but not sufficient for a reaction to occur. There must be an interaction matrix element. Far from being simple, I think this question touches on the mystery of the structure of the electron.

Answer (score 0):

In fact photons are "messengers" (Gauge Bosons) of the Electro-Magnetic forces (it's a fundamental interaction). If you use (use could be "convert") photons it rely on the EM if I'm not mistaken.

There isn't a mysterious force which convert the messengers of a fundamental force into mater. It's simply authorized by the conservations laws.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process :

The inverse process of e- e+ annihilation is still complicated. We have no laser sufficiently powerfull to create a pair with photons. The probability of this kind of event is very low.

Comment: In what way are photons messengers? Do you mean that they carry information about their source?

Comment: Not about the source but about a process, if we can say that the amount of energy (eg) is a kind of information. But more of that they interact with charged particles. They are "messenger" in that sense that if the two charged particles are two man, they exchange photon like a balloon to interact, to "communicate" . That was the sens of my sentence.

Comment: This does not sound like physics.

Comment: @my2cts, I believe WilliamFr is simply answering in accordance with many 'popular' science books on the subject.

Comment: Answers on this site must be based on physics, not on popular science books. The link given does meet this requirement, though.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* WilliamFr!  There may be some push-back to your answer because it reads a bit *naive* but don't be discouraged!  If you stick around long enough, there's a lot that can be learned here if that's what it is you're after.

Comment: I'm not discouraged :) I understand that my answer is not sufficient. I'm not a Particle Physicist and there is a lot of things I don't understand about this. In fact I would point that it couldn't be the "Weak Nuclear Force" which convert photon on electrons. Because Weak Nuclear Force imply W and Z boson. Not Photons. More or that a Force which imply photon is "by nature" an electromagnetic force.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the formula $E^2-p^2=m^2$, where $E,p,m$ represent energy, momentum, and mass, respectively.  Deriving this is a bit tricky if you don’t know the proper formulas for energy and momentum; check out [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation) link for more.

On a side note, just as a neat thing most people who don’t study this stuff in-depth don’t know:  $E^2$ does not equal $mc^2$ exactly, especially at relativistic speeds.  The actual equation is $E= \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}$. That might actually be $E^2$ not $E$; I can’t quite remember and don’t have my notes with me.